# Marginal Distribution of the sum of Bernoulli rv

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

consider the conditional on probabilities $p_1, \ldots, p_n$, with independent Bernoulli random variables $Y_1, ..., Y_n$

given that 
$P(Y_i = 1\mid p_1, \ldots, p_n) = p_i, \  P(Y_i = 0\mid p_1, \ldots, p_n) = 1 − p_i$  for  $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

if each $p_i$ is a random draw from a distribution with mean $p$.
we are looking for the distribution of $X = Y_1 + \cdots + Y_n$.

I am thinking that $X$ follows a bin. distribution. Am I wrong?

Comment: how about this
to recursively obtain the probability mass function
of $Y_1 + · · · + Y_k$, first for k = 1, then k = 2, and on up to k = n. 
$P_k(j) = P{Y_1 + · · · + Y_k = j}$

For $0 < j < k$, conditioning on $Y_k$ yields the recursion

$P_k(j) = P{Y_1 + · · · + Y_k= j |Y_k = 1}p_k +P{Y_1 + · · · + Y_k = j|Y_k = 0}q_k$

$= P{Y_1 + · · · + Y_k−1 = j − 1|Y_k = 1}p_k
+ P{Y_1 + · · · + Y_k−1 = j|Y_k = 0}q_k$

$= P{Y_1 + · · · + Y_k−1 = j − 1}p_k + P{Y_1 + · · · + Y_k−1 = j}q_k$

$= p_k P_k−1(j − 1) + q_k P_k−1(j)$

this is the final formula. am I correct?

Comment: @MichaelHardy What do you think?

Comment: how about this to recursively obtain the probability mass function of $Y_1+⋅⋅⋅+Y_k$, we induct on $k = 1$, then $k = 2$, then to $k = n$. 

so we have $P_k(j)=P(Y_1+⋅⋅⋅+Y_k = j) $

For $0<j<k$, 

conditioning on $Y_k$ yields the recursion $P_k(j)=PY1+⋅⋅⋅+Y_k=j  | Y_k = 1)p_k+P(Y_1+⋅⋅⋅+Y_k = j | Y_k=0)q_k = P(Y_1+⋅⋅⋅+Y_{k−1} = j−1 | Y_k = 1)p_k+P(Y_1+⋅⋅⋅+Y_{k−1} = j | Y_k = 0)q_k =P(Y_1+⋅⋅⋅+Y_{k−1}=j-1)p_k+P(Y_1+⋅⋅⋅+Y_{k−1}=j)q_k =p_kP_{k−1}(j−1)+q_kP_{k−1}(j) $

and this would be the final formula. am I correct?